# To what point or points does the sequence converge?

Tags: general-topology

*In the finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , to what point or points does the sequence $\{x_{n}\} $ converge* ?
Here is my solution-

Let $G$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. i.e., $X-G$ is finite . Then sequence $\{x_{n}\} \in G$ for all but finitely many $n$. Therefore $\{x_{n}\}\to x$.

What to do next actaully I am confused

Comment: Look at this answer: [For a finite complement topology, to which point or points does the sequence converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272790/for-a-finite-complement-topology-to-which-point-or-points-does-the-sequence-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. i.e., $X-G$ is finite . Then sequence $\{x_{n}\} \in G$ for all but finitely many $n$. Therefore $\{x_{n}\}\to x$. Since every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is distinct. There are only a finite number of points of sequence that may not be lie  in $G$. So the sequence converge to every pont of $\mathbb{R}_{FC}$

Comment: What about the sequence $(0,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$? It does not converge to anything.